# PayPal Chained Payment Node.js

Tags: node.js, paypal, chained-payments

I am creating a website and i want to implement Paypal chained payment. Is there any exaple of how to use it with Node.js. Or can someone explain to me how can i integrete it in a React website?

Comment: Check Brad Traversy course's repo https://github.com/bradtraversy/proshop_mern he uses in a MERN proyect, the course is on Udemy and is very good https://github.com/bradtraversy/proshop_mern
https://github.com/bradtraversy/proshop_mern/commit/b7b00e77da97587d89c4d32943b3921e3f881f14

Comment: Hey @Angelo did you manage to find an answer to your question, I am also looking for the same thing